# time complexity of set comprehension vs tuple comprehension vs list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension, set-comprehension

I am learning python and was checking out the `timeit` module. I am trying the exact same thing with the `list`, `set` and `tuple` to check the overheads involved. Please take a gander (IPython shell) :-

`>>> timeit {x**9 for x in range(100)}`
`>>> 49.3 µs ± 229 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)`

`>>> timeit (x**9 for x in range(100))`
`>>> 830 ns ± 6.39 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)`

`>>> timeit [x**9 for x in range(100)]`
`>>> 45.8 µs ± 346 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)`

I get that `tuple` comprehension is fastest because it doesn't have any of the overhead of `set` and `list`, eg. `hash` calculation and duplicate removal in `set` or order preservation of elements in `list`.

But what I do not understand is that the `set comprehension` and `list comprehension` take almost equivalent time. I want to know why is the `set comprehension` is not very much slower than the `list comprehension` as in a `set`, the compiler has the overhead of computing the `hash value` of every entry and check for duplicates while `list comprehension` don't have to.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: `(x**9 for x in range(100))` is *not* a tuple comprehension. It is a generator, which has to be looped over again to access each value that is yielded at a particular iteration. Thus, that is why the latter is supposedly the fastest, because only the generator object has been created.

Comment: `%timeit tuple(x**9 for x in range(100))` -> 48.5 µs (51.8 µs for the set and 43.3 µs for the list)

Comment: Also, *hashing is the duplicate removal*. There isn't two separate things going on. It is the nature of a hash set that it will only create an array with values unique by hash. The uniqueness comes for free. But as others have pointed out, it should be **very curious** that the "tuple comprehension" is that much faster. `tuple` and `list` object constructions have almost exactly the same overhead, except lists are often a tiny bit less memory efficient. But what you have here is a *generator expression*, not a "tuple comprehension", which doesn't exist.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks, you were lucid enough to clear the cobwebs of doubts. :-)